# Can't install public github repositories listed in package.json

Tags: javascript, git, package.json, git-clone

[image: github repository install error]

I'm getting

> You may not have access to this repository or it no longer exist in this workspace. If you think this repository exists and you have access, make sure you are authenticated

The repository is public and my other computer can install dependencies. I can't clone any github repository using https either.

The dependency is listed like this:

```
"react-native-safe-area-view": "https://github.com/johhansantana/react-native-safe-area-view.git",
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on MacOS had this exact same issue. Tried researching everywhere and attempting everything I could find online. After giving up, decided to look at my git configuration file in `$HOME/.gitconfig`. I found that I had a configuration that was changing my "https://github.com" for "USERNAME@bibucket.com". After removing said configuration, it started working as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).